# how to update a row in django using a form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I'm trying to make a website to track my volunteers' attendance using django, there will be a check/in and a check/out button so when the check/in button is clicked the data will go to the database there is no problem with that the problem is in the check/out button, when the check/out button is clicked it should update the row and add the date/time of the check/out.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create your models here.

class Volunteer(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Login(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="", null=True,)
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="", null=True,)
    check_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    check_out = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    check_in.editable=True
    check_out.editable=True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Volunteer, Login
from django import forms
# Create your views here. 


def volunteerView(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        print ("Recieved a POST request")
        form=LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print ("FORM is valid")
        else:
            print ("FORM is unvalid")
    all_volunteers = Volunteer.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'volunteer.html',
        {'all_volunteers': all_volunteers, 'form':LoginForm()})

def loginView(request):
    login_view = Login.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'login.html',
    {'login_view': login_view})



def addVolunteer(request):
    new_volunteer = Volunteer(full_name = request.POST['full_name'],
    phone_number = request.POST['phone_number'],
    email = request.POST['email'],
    national_id = request.POST['national_id'],
    )
    new_volunteer.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def addChekIn(request):
    new_checkin = Login(
        national_id = request.POST['national_id'],
        full_name = request.POST['full_name'],
    )
    new_checkin.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

template/login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ertiqa | Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<style>

h1{
    color: white;
}


</style>

<body>

    <form action="/addCheckIN/" method="POST" class="container">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h1>Check IN</h1>
        <h3>Full Name</h3>
        <input type="text" name="full_name"><br>
        <h3>National ID</h3>
        <input type="text" name="national_id"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Check IN" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! You need to add what you have tried for us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your problem. First of all, your models.py fiction is little bit wrong. You can use model classes like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create your models here.

class Volunteer(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Login(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="", null=True)
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="", null=True)
    check_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=True) # <--- You can use editable arg inline.
    check_out = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=True) # <--- You can use editable arg inline.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

I think you don't use any authorization session. Just someone fill inputs and post these infos to db. Why do you need two class as "Volunteer" and "Login"? Have they any relation or do you need two models? Maybe it's better than that:

```
class Volunteer(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    check_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=True) #<-- auto_now_add=True args mean: when you call .save() method first time, this field is filled in with the current date and time.
    check_out = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=True) #<-- auto_now=True args mean: when you call .save() method second and next times (every updating), this field is filled in with the current date and time.


    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

You need two function, first one was done (def addCheckIn) so you call .save() method for save new Volunteers. Second one is for update (like def checkout(request)). So you should call .save() method again like these:

```
def checkout(request):
    national_id = request.POST['national_id'], # If national_id is unique, It's enough.
    try: #Check this national id is exist in your db.
        person = Login.objects.get(national_id=national_id)
        person.save()
        messages.success(request, "Thank you for checkout blabla")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')  # Maybe you can create a success page.
    except LoginDoesNotExist: # If doesn't you can show error message.
        messages.error(request, "No such registry was found in the system.")
        return redirect("/login/")
```

Last one, when you give name to functions, you should use underscore not camel case. (like def add_check_in()). It's just pep8 Python spelling rule.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very very much!! I'm new to django so I'm not that good, Thanks for helping

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget that If no one helps each other, we cannot live in this world ;)